# Is there a short/common name for form-based user interfaces?

Tags: terminology

We're all familiar with CLI and GUI but it doesn't seem to me that a UI consisting mostly of links and text fields is really a GUI.  Think of something like on-line banking where any graphics are really only decorative.  You're unlikely to use drag and drop to accomplish a transfer between accounts.  Is there a name for such a UI?  I'm looking for a name independent of implementation: might be a desktop program, might be a web page, might be a mobile app.  TIA.

Comment: It's still a GUI.

Answer (score 3):

I think you actually used the most common expression for it in your question: Form-based interface. And I [quote](https://jfk-computing.wikispaces.com/Form-based+interface+definition+-+Michael+McAndrew):

> **Form-based Interface definition.**
>
> A type of user interface used, for example, on the internet, to organize
> questions or options for the user so that they resemble a traditional
> paper form to be filled out by pointing to the fields and typing text,
> or by choosing from a list.

And yet [another](http://www.gitta.info/DBSysConcept/en/html/DBLanguages_learningObject3.html):

> This interface consist of forms which are adapted to the user. He/She
> can fill in all of the fields and make new entries to the database or
> only some of the fields to query the other ones. But some operations
> might be restricted by the application.  Form-based user interfaces
> are wide spread and are a very important means of interacting with a
> DBMS. They are easy to use and have the advantage that the user does
> not need special knowledge about database languages like SQL.

The example image in the last quoted site is actually quite illustrative of the type of app you are describing:

[image: Form-based interface]

The Form-based interface expression is likely the most generic, yet others exist in more specific contexts. Such is the case for the [Webform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_(HTML)):

> A webform, web form or HTML form on a web page allows a user to enter
> data that is sent to a server for processing. Forms can resemble paper
> or database forms because web users fill out the forms using
> checkboxes, radio buttons, or text fields. For example, forms can be
> used to enter shipping or credit card data to order a product, or can
> be used to retrieve search results from a search engine.

Notice that, although the most generic, it does not mean its some kind of standard. In the web site [UI-patterns](http://ui-patterns.com/), more specifically in their [Design Patterns](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns) you will find all kinds of expressions to designate mostly unnamed styles. The one you are looking for is "[Fill in the Blanks](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/FillInTheBlanks)", and I quote:

> The “Fill in the blanks” makes the interface somewhat
> self-explanatory. Our semantic capabilities as human beings allow us
> to fill in the missing parts of a sentence.

Also: check the [Input Prompt Pattern](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/InputPrompt).

Comment: So the acronym is FBI? :-)

Comment: In user experience we despise acronyms due to the confusion it causes ;-)

Comment: @SteveD LOL, WEG. IMHO I completely agree. J/K.